# Audio player shows and disappear in Firefox

Tags: html, audio

I try to use HTML5's audio tag to play a music file on my site. This is my syntax:  


The problem I am encountering is that when I refresh my page, I can see the player, but only for a few seconds, then it fade out.

Comment: Please share the code you have written.

Comment: I don't know why the code is not showing. I typed it here. Please I'm a newbie to stack exchange. This is my syntax: <audio controls="controls"> <source type="audio/ogg" src="horse.ogg"></source>
<source type="audio/mp3" src="horse.mp3"></source>
</audio>

Comment: You need to format code as code in textarea

Comment: Add autoplay="autoplay" . Also do you have actual files available as specified in src or you have just copied the code from w3 for learning, and actual music files are not available.

Comment: I copied the audio files in the same directory as my index.html. My challenge is that the control and UI for the audio player will not show on screen but it's space is available on the screen. I also added autoplay but still no show. Thank you